# How does distance_recorder work in boost graph library?

Tags: boost, boost-graph

I am learning breath first search algorithm. The graph is a complete binary tree. I want to print the distance of each node to the root. For example, `d[0, 0] = 0, d[0, 1] = 1, d[0, 2] = 1, d[0, 3] = 2, d[0, 7] = 3`.

[image]

The dot file is here.

```
digraph G {
0;
1;
2;
3;
4;
5;
6;
7;
8;
9;
10;
11;
12;
13;
14;
0->1 ;
0->2 ;
1->3 ;
1->4 ;
2->5 ;
2->6 ;
3->7 ;
3->8 ;
4->9 ;
4->10 ;
5->11 ;
5->12 ;
6->13 ;
6->14 ;
}
```

The program is pretty straightforward, `make_bfs_visitor` take a `distance_recorder` to record the distance between tree edges.

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/breadth_first_search.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graphviz.hpp>

int main()
{
    using DiGraph = boost::adjacency_list<>;
    DiGraph g;
    std::ifstream dot_file("graph.dot");
    boost::dynamic_properties dp{ boost::ignore_other_properties };
    boost::read_graphviz(dot_file, g, dp);

    auto vd0 = *boost::vertices(g).first;

    using vertices_size_type = boost::graph_traits<DiGraph>::vertices_size_type;

    std::vector<vertices_size_type> distances(boost::num_vertices(g));
    auto dist_pmap = boost::make_iterator_property_map(
        distances.begin(), get(boost::vertex_index, g));

    auto vis = boost::make_bfs_visitor(
        boost::record_distances(dist_pmap, boost::on_tree_edge()));

    boost::breadth_first_search(g, vd0, visitor(vis));

    for (auto d : distances)
        std::cout << d << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    for (auto d : boost::make_iterator_range(boost::vertices(g)))
      std::cout << d << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

The output is not what I expected.

```
0 1 3 3 3 3 3 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How does it work?

`record_distances` is a factory for an event visitor. `make_bfs_visitor` ties that into an (otherwise default) BFS visitor model.

I'm guessing this wasn't your question. It's not clear what you *do* expect, as the output doesn't look at all informative to me. Perhaps you want to display it in a more useful format:

```
for (auto vd : boost::make_iterator_range(boost::vertices(g)))
    std::cout << "d[" << vd0 << ", " << vd << "] = " << distances.at(vd) << "\n";
```

Now the output is:

```
d[0, 0] = 0
d[0, 1] = 1
d[0, 2] = 3
d[0, 3] = 3
d[0, 4] = 3
d[0, 5] = 3
d[0, 6] = 3
d[0, 7] = 1
d[0, 8] = 2
d[0, 9] = 2
d[0, 10] = 2
d[0, 11] = 2
d[0, 12] = 3
d[0, 13] = 3
d[0, 14] = 3
```

Now, what gives? Because in the heading of your question you suggest you expect:

> For example, d[0, 0] = 0, d[0, 1] = 1, d[0, 2] = 1, d[0, 3] = 2, d[0, 7] = 3.

There's a clear mismatch! `d[0,7] = 1`  doesn't match the "more logical" `d[0,7] = 3`. Yet, you didn't do anything /wrong/ and the distance calculation isn't wrong.

There's a subtle observer error! You *think* vertex descriptor 7 refers to the vertex that you showed with that number in the input. However, if you print the graph that `read_graphviz` reads:

[image]

AHA! Something went wrong, or *differently than you expected*. In fact, if you removed the "magic bit" about `ignore_other_properties` that you didn't actually know the meaning of:

```
boost::dynamic_properties dp; // {boost::ignore_other_properties};
```

You'd have been told about it:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::property_not_found> >'
  what():  Property not found: node_id.
```

Indeed, you told Boost to *read the vertices*, but to ignore the vertex id from the Dot file. So, the result is a guaranteed *isomorphism* of the graph in your input, but the IDs are in unspecified/implementation-defined order.

### Fixing It: read a node id

Let's keep with `adjacency_list<>` pure and simple, so lets create an external id map:

```
DiGraph g;
std::map<DiGraph::vertex_descriptor, int> vertex_ids;

auto id_map = boost::make_assoc_property_map(vertex_ids);
boost::dynamic_properties dp;
dp.property("node_id", id_map);

std::ifstream dot_file("graph.dot");
boost::read_graphviz(dot_file, g, dp);
```

Now, when we write the graph back using the original node ids:

```
boost::dynamic_properties dp;
dp.property("node_id", get(boost::vertex_index, g));

std::ofstream dot_file("output.dot");
boost::write_graphviz_dp(dot_file, g, dp);
```

We get our original picture back. Phew.

> **Note** For recording the distances we still keep using the "technical" `vertex_descriptor` as the implicit vertex-id. This is because that makes it easier to use the `vector<>` as the distance-map.
>
> Alternatively, we can use the "user-friendly" id_map and store in an associative `LvaluePropertMap`

### Use the node-id in the report

From here it's relatively easy to fix the reporting:

```
for (auto vd : boost::make_iterator_range(boost::vertices(g)))
    std::cout << "d[" << id_map[vd0] << ", " << id_map[vd] << "] = " << distances.at(vd) << "\n";
```

Prints:

```
d[0, 0] = 0
d[0, 1] = 1
...
d[0, 6] = 2
d[0, 7] = 3
...
```

Yay! Sanity restored.

### Bonus: Visualizing the distances

Let's add a label to each edge displaying the distance from root to its target vertex:

```
std::map<DiGraph::edge_descriptor, int> edge_labels;
auto label_map = boost::make_assoc_property_map(edge_labels);

for (auto ed : boost::make_iterator_range(boost::edges(g)))
    label_map[ed] = distances.at(target(ed, g));

boost::dynamic_properties dp;
dp.property("node_id", id_map);
dp.property("label", label_map);

std::ofstream dot_file("output.dot");
boost::write_graphviz_dp(dot_file, g, dp);
```

Now, we have this beautiful, reassuring output:

[image]

### Full Demo Listing

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/breadth_first_search.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graphviz.hpp>
using DiGraph = boost::adjacency_list<>;

int main()
{
    DiGraph g;
    std::map<DiGraph::vertex_descriptor, int> vertex_ids;

    auto id_map = boost::make_assoc_property_map(vertex_ids);
    {
        boost::dynamic_properties dp;
        dp.property("node_id", id_map);

        std::ifstream dot_file("graph.dot");
        boost::read_graphviz(dot_file, g, dp);
    }

    auto vd0 = *boost::vertices(g).first;

    std::vector<int> distances(boost::num_vertices(g));
    auto dist_pmap = boost::make_iterator_property_map(distances.begin(), get(boost::vertex_index, g));

    auto vis = boost::make_bfs_visitor(
        boost::record_distances(dist_pmap, boost::on_tree_edge()));

    boost::breadth_first_search(g, vd0, visitor(vis));

    for (auto vd : boost::make_iterator_range(boost::vertices(g)))
        std::cout << "d[" << id_map[vd0] << ", " << id_map[vd] << "] = " << distances.at(vd) << "\n";

    {
        std::map<DiGraph::edge_descriptor, int> edge_labels;
        auto label_map = boost::make_assoc_property_map(edge_labels);

        for (auto ed : boost::make_iterator_range(boost::edges(g)))
            label_map[ed] = distances.at(target(ed, g));

        boost::dynamic_properties dp;
        dp.property("node_id", id_map);
        dp.property("label", label_map);

        std::ofstream dot_file("output.dot");
        boost::write_graphviz_dp(dot_file, g, dp);
    }
}
```

---

Comment: That's a great answer. I agree this question(title) itself is poorly worded. I will add a note in my question to reflect that.